# Playwright : How can I select and click inside an iframe without timeout exceeding?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, playwright

Im scraping a page that shows a captcha which I want to select and click. The first problem is that i always get errors as
`page.waitForSelector: Timeout 30000ms exceeded`
How can I make it wait longer?
or I get error `Target page, context or browser has been closed` before the click event hapens.

Also if that captcha is not shown (lets say only half the time) but the actual webpage, because Im waiting for the captcha, it will exceed the time and the rest of the code wont be run.
How can I continue with the code if there is no captcha shown?

```
const getHtmlPlaywright = () => {
  const browser = await {chromium}["chromium"].launch({chromiumSandbox: false})
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage()
  await page.goto("www.example.com");
            
  const captchaFrame = await page.waitForSelector("iframe[title='reCAPTCHA']");
  const captchaFrameContent = await captchaFrame.contentFrame();
  const captchaCheckbox = await captchaFrameContent.waitForSelector("#g- 
  recaptcha-response");
  const formSubmit = await page.waitForSelector("#recaptcha-form");
  await captchaCheckbox.click();
  await formSubmit.click();

  const html = await page.content();
  await context.close();
  await browser.close();
  return html;
}
```

Im trying to access an iframe inside a form and click it.

```
 <form id="recaptcha-form" action="..." method="post" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="onCaptchaSubmit">
          <div>
             <div>
                <iframe
                    title="reCAPTCHA"
                    ...          
                    src="..."
                ></iframe>
             </div>
                <textarea
                   id="g-recaptcha-response"
                   class="g-recaptcha-response"
                   style="..., display: none;"
                ></textarea>
             </div>
                <iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
          </div>
   <input type="submit" class="chip" value="Continue" disabled="disabled" />
  </form>
```

Comment: `"www.example.com"` doesn't reproduce the captcha. You can use `try`/`catch` to handle the timeout error and move on with the code. Consider also adding a human user agent or running headfully to help avoid detection.

Comment: Is it that you want to solve reCAPTCHA with 3 lines of code?

Comment: so as for the captcha its just 2 clicks -> click on input checkbox and submit, nothing else involved, so yes I thought locating the element and clicking would be enough.

Comment: @ggorlen yes I have of course a try catch. if there is no captcha event, it wont help me that it goes into the catch, as in that case I would want to access the html of the page. Or do you mean, I should handle the case that there is captcha in the catch?! Regardless of this, it anyways doesnt work because the timeout is triggered and I am still wondering what to do about it

Comment: Maybe my comment wasn't clear--the `try` is around the `waitForSelector` that waits for the captcha, as well as any code that deals with the captcha. If it throws, then you're in a `catch` block where there is no capcha and you can continue on with the normal webpage. It's like an `if`/`else` (which can be done with `page.$`, but this doesn't wait, which may or may not be necessary depending on your actual site).